# Azure Text Analytics API to Power BI - error: Web.Contents failed to get contents

Tags: powerbi, azure-cognitive-services

My goal is to get a new column in Power BI with keyphrases based on a column with text data. I try to connect the Azure text analytics API to PowerBI. I use this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/tutorials/tutorial-power-bi-key-phrases

After I invoke the custom function, and set the authentication and privacy to "anonymous" and "public", the KeyPhrases column I get only contains the values "Error" with the following description:

An error occurred in the ‘’ query. DataSource.Error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from 'https://******.cognitiveservices.azure.com/.cognitiveservices.azure.com/text/analytics/v2.1/keyPhrases' (404): Resource Not Found
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Web
    DataSourcePath=https://*******.cognitiveservices.azure.com/.cognitiveservices.azure.com/text/analytics/v2.1/keyPhrases
    Url=https://******.cognitiveservices.azure.com/.cognitiveservices.azure.com/text/analytics/v2.1/keyPhrases

Also, not sure if it is related to my issue, but I see the following warning on my Azure account in the Networking menu: 
"VNet setting is not supported for current API type or resource location."

I checked all the steps in the tutorial, I re-entered the authentication and privacy settings. Also, I tried the same for the sentiment analysis function. Finally, I tried everything on a different and very simplistic dataset.

Not sure what the cause of my issue is and how to solve it.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Best, Rosanne

Answer (score 0):

Look at your error message:

```
'https://******.cognitiveservices.azure.com/.cognitiveservices.azure.com/text/analytics/v2.1/keyPhrases' (404): Resource Not Found Details: DataSourceKind=Web DataSourcePath=https://*******.cognitiveservices.azure.com/.cognitiveservices.azure.com/text/analytics/v2.1/keyPhrases Url=https://******.cognitiveservices.azure.com/.cognitiveservices.azure.com/text/analytics/v2.1/keyPhrases
```

It throw a 404, so you are pointing to the wrong URL.
And s you can see in the beginning of your url:

https://******.cognitiveservices.azure.com/.cognitiveservices.azure.com << here you have twice ".cognitiveservices.azure.com/" so you url setup is wrong.

I don't know exactly how it is setup on your side, but you may have provided a region or endpoint during it and it's here where you put the wrong value.